# My Pom.xml is only running junit 4 test cases not juint 5 test cases

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit4, junit5

I had unit tests of both junit 4 and junit 5 in my project. Now when i run my test cases through **mvn clean install** or **mvn test**. it only runs junit 4 test cases. It does not run junit 5 test cases. Can anyone help me to understand the issue I have in my POM.xml due to which only junit 4 test cases are running with maven commands.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.34</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>tirebatteryservice</name>
    <description>tirebatteryservice</description>

    <properties>
        <tbc.version>1.0.0</tbc.version>
        <jms.version>1.1</jms.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.4</lombok.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.8.1</commons-lang3.version>
        <fastjson.version>2.0.12</fastjson.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.2</spring.boot.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.apache.commons.collections.version>3.2.1</org.apache.commons.collections.version>
        <jacoco.maven.plugin.version>0.7.8</jacoco.maven.plugin.version>
        <testng.version>6.8</testng.version>
        <azure.log.version>2.2.1</azure.log.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <elasticsearch.version>6.6.1</elasticsearch.version>
        <ejml.version>0.23</ejml.version>
        <powermock.version>2.0.0-beta.5</powermock.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
        <tbc-common.version>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT</tbc-common.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.108</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.gpedro.integrations.slack</groupId>
            <artifactId>slack-webhook</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>${jms.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>${fastjson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--For Open API V3 Swagger specification-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jacoco -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--enables unit tests to run-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application insights -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.log.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- stanford -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejml</artifactId>
            <version>0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- sonar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.3.2</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.3.2</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sams.member.platform.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>ccpa-access</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Azure Key Vault Dependency  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--TBC COMMON-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sams.clubops.tbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>tbc-common</artifactId>
            <version>${tbc-common.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mockito dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.sams.clubops.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>Dockerfile</include>
                                        <include>startup.sh</include>
                                        <include>sshd_config</include>
                                        <include>ssh_setup.sh</include>
                                        <include>proxy-intranet-ref-app.conf</include>
                                        <include>nginx-rproxy-secure.conf</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/printTemplates</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/com/sams/clubops/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

<!--                    Restores original classes as they were before offline instrumentation.-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coveo</groupId>
                <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <displayLimit>10</displayLimit>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

While my test classes look like as following class

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

public class BayControllerTest {

  private static final int OK_STATUS = 200;
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @InjectMocks private BayController bayController;
  @Mock private BayService bayService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(bayController).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFetchBayInfo_Success() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(bayService.findBayInfo(anyLong())).thenReturn(buildBayBOList());
    MvcResult mvcResult =
        mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/appointment/bayInfo/4969"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(OK_STATUS, status);
    assertEquals(SUCCESS_CODE, JSONObject.parseObject(content).get("code"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testFetchBayInfo_Failure() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(bayService.findBayInfo(anyLong())).thenThrow(ApplicationException.class);
    MvcResult mvcResult =
        mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/appointment/bayInfo/4969"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(OK_STATUS, status);
    assertEquals(ERROR_CODE, JSONObject.parseObject(content).get("code"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testReloadBayInfo_Success() throws Exception {
    Mockito.doReturn(buildBayInfo()).when(bayService).refreshBayInfo(Mockito.anyBoolean());
    MvcResult mvcResult =
        mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/appointment/reloadBayInfo"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(OK_STATUS, status);
    assertEquals(SUCCESS_CODE, JSONObject.parseObject(content).get("code"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testReloadBayInfo_Failure() throws Exception {
    Mockito.doThrow(new ApplicationException())
        .when(bayService)
        .refreshBayInfo(Mockito.anyBoolean());
    MvcResult mvcResult =
        mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/appointment/reloadBayInfo"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(OK_STATUS, status);
    assertEquals(ERROR_CODE, JSONObject.parseObject(content).get("code"));
  }

  private Map<Long, List<ClubBayBO>> buildBayInfo() {

    Map<Long, List<ClubBayBO>> bayMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<ClubBayBO> bayList = new ArrayList<>();
    bayList.add(buildBayBO());
    bayMap.put((long) 4969, bayList);
    return bayMap;
  }

  private ClubBayBO buildBayBO() {
    ClubBayBO bayBO = new ClubBayBO();
    bayBO.setBayId(1L);
    bayBO.setBayNbr(100);
    bayBO.setClubNbr(4969);
    bayBO.setDescription("This is the bay for Bentonville club");
    bayBO.setBayAvailable(true);
    return bayBO;
  }

  private List<ClubBayBO> buildBayBOList() {
    List<ClubBayBO> bayBoList = new ArrayList<>();
    bayBoList.add(buildBayBO());
    return bayBoList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your maven-surefire-plugin?

Comment: Go back to a revision where junit 5 worked, then test other revisions until you find the change which broke things.

Comment: And why are you mixing two versions of junit?

Comment: actually @tgdavies I have now upgraded all my junit 4 test cases to junit 5 test cases. Now I have only junit 5 test cases in my project but maven only runs junit 4 test cases it is not running upgraded junit 5 test cases.

Comment: Which unit testing framework do you use? JUnit Jupiter, TestNG or JUnit 4?? You have several dependencies also using powermock (which is JUnit 4 based) furthermore if you like to use JUnit Jupiter you have to use version 2.22.2 as minimum of maven-surefire-plugin (also for maven-failsafe-plugin) or better use most recent version 3.0.0-M7... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @khmarbaise can you point out which dependencies in my POM are using powermockito ? while I ma using Jupiter as mentioned in my POM.

Comment: Could you please include a sample test that you're trying to run and which is not working properly?

Comment: @AlexanderGolovnya I have edited my question and added one test class, You can look at that in question.

Comment: @Johonsmuthio I've posted a working example with runnable tests, please check if it'll work for you

Answer (score 0):

Your project is apparently a Spring Boot application because your pom.xml file has `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent. Spring Boot specifies dependency and plugin versions that were curated to work with that Spring Boot version. By convention, a Spring Boot project typically uses the dependency and plugin versions specified by Spring Boot.

Your pom.xml file overrides the `maven-surefire-plugin` version that Spring Boot would have used. If you delete the element:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then your project will execute the `maven-surefire-plugin` version capable of running JUnit 5 tests.

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to be running 2.22.x of the Surefire plugin to get JUnit 5 compatibility. See the [JIRAs included in those releases](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1330?jql=project%20%3D%20SUREFIRE%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20(2.22.0%2C%202.22.1%2C%202.22.2)%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20key) and note particularly [SUREFIRE-1330](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1330). Then ensure the POM includes a `junit-vintage-engine` dependency.

P.S. For folks wondering "why have both JUnit 4 and 5" - the [JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4) says it best:

> ...it is not expected that source code maintainers will need to update all of their existing tests, test extensions, and custom build test infrastructure to migrate to JUnit Jupiter.

> Instead, JUnit provides a gentle migration path via a JUnit Vintage test engine which allows existing tests based on JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 to be executed using the JUnit Platform infrastructure.

This approach is wonderful for large legacy codebases that can't be upgraded big-bang.

Comment: Why I need junit-vintage-engine dependency in my POM.xml specifically. when we know that spring boot starter project brings junit 5 dependency with it. So then we need to specifically include junit-vintage-engine dependency ?

Comment: [Spring Boot dependencies for version 2.7.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.2). Note, no vintage engine. Spring Boot 2.7.2 only supports JUnit 5 by default; JUnit 4 requires the VIntage dependency to be separately added.

Answer (score 0):

As of JUnit 5.4, you can replace these dependencies with a single one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So it makes sense to update to the latest JUnit version and replace these dependencies with this one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But this is just for the beauty. To resolve your issue try upgrading to the latest version of the Maven Surefire plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
</plugin>
```

Please refer to this full example of the `pom.xml file`. I've omitted a few of your dependencies to quickly reproduce it on my computer:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demotest</name>
    <description>demotest</description>

    <properties>
        <tbc.version>1.0.0</tbc.version>
        <jms.version>1.1</jms.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.4</lombok.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.8.1</commons-lang3.version>
        <fastjson.version>2.0.12</fastjson.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.2</spring.boot.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.apache.commons.collections.version>3.2.1</org.apache.commons.collections.version>
        <jacoco.maven.plugin.version>0.7.8</jacoco.maven.plugin.version>
        <testng.version>6.8</testng.version>
        <azure.log.version>2.2.1</azure.log.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <elasticsearch.version>6.6.1</elasticsearch.version>
        <ejml.version>0.23</ejml.version>
        <powermock.version>2.0.0-beta.5</powermock.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
        <tbc-common.version>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT</tbc-common.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.108</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.gpedro.integrations.slack</groupId>
            <artifactId>slack-webhook</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>${fastjson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--For Open API V3 Swagger specification-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jacoco -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--enables unit tests to run-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application insights -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.log.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- stanford -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejml</artifactId>
            <version>0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- sonar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Azure Key Vault Dependency  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mockito dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demotest.DemotestApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/com/sams/clubops/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <!--                    Restores original classes as they were before offline instrumentation.-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemotestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemotestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The simplified test class:

```java
package com.example.demotest;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

public class BayControllerTest {

    private static final int OK_STATUS = 200;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFetchBayInfo_Success() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/appointment/bayInfo/4969"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(OK_STATUS, status);
    }
}
```

Logs from the `mvn clean install` run:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.example:demotest >------------------------
[INFO] Building demotest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Deleting /demotest/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent (default) @ demotest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /demotest/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:instrument (default-instrument) @ demotest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /demotest/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /demotest/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ demotest ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.demotest.BayControllerTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.243 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demotest.BayControllerTest
[ERROR] com.example.demotest.BayControllerTest.testFetchBayInfo_Success  Time elapsed: 1.194 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.demotest.BayControllerTest.testFetchBayInfo_Success(BayControllerTest.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   BayControllerTest.testFetchBayInfo_Success:27 NullPointer
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.679 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-09T13:16:04+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) on project demotest: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to demotest/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```